# function declared globally in main() is not in scope of qt widget slot

Tags: c++, qt, function, scope, slot

I have a qt widget GUI with a button that signals a slot in the QMainWindow. This slot calls a function that is defined in the header of main(), but seems to be undefined once its called from the slot.

Roughly, the problem like this:

```
#include <required libraries like stdio.h>
#include "window.h"

void testfunc() {printf("I really want to print this");}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My MainWindow object's constructor looks basically like

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_pressed()
{
    testfunc(); //Error: Not in this scope.
}
```

I'm not sure why the problem occurs. I have tried unsuccessfully changing the order of the #includes in main() to

```
#include <stdio.h>
void testfunc() {printf("I really want to print this");}
#include "window.h"
```

Perhaps the problem occurs because the QApplication 'a' that is called by 'a.exec()' that handles QMainWindow's slot does not have testfunc() in its scope?

Another odd thing is some libraries that I have #included already in main() must be re-included in mainwindow.h to be referenced.

There is also some "Dynamic linking" occuring in one of the libraries in main, i'm not sure if this is causing problems.

What is going on?

How do I extend the scope of the function to the slot?

---

edit: Ok, I have a "library.h" I #include and use in "main.cpp". This library has classes and function definitions that are used the the definition a class in "window.h" and its member functions in "window.cpp", and an object of this class is constructed in main().

Do I have to `#include "library.h"` on the top of window.cpp and/or window.h?

Comment: The header system is very primitive - `#include "file"` only means "insert the contents of the file 'file' right here". It doesn't affect any files except the one where it occurs.

Comment: So I have two .cpp files. "main.cpp" and "window.cpp", and a "window.h" file, where "window" is a class. I create a window object in main(). I want to use the same libraries across all these three files. Do I have to #include the libraries across all three, or just the two .cpp files, just main.cpp, or is there some other rule to help me keep track of all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does the file that has `void MainWindow::on_radioButton_pressed()` know what `testfunc()` is if you don't include it?  Some way you need to include `testfunc()` in that file.  One way is to move `testfunc()` into its own header and included it where its needed.

Comment: I thought that #include is basically a "copy and paste", which is why I figured testfunc() was in the scope of mainwindow.h and its associated mainwindow.cpp. No? I have to look more closely at my code, will return to edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: You were correct, but I couldn't include the header because the header used dynamic linking and for some reason couldn't be included without errors. I found one that did not use it. Go figure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the difference between **define** and **declare** a function.
Read this first:

http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

so you need to *declare* the function in a header file, call it myglobalvars.h.
Include myglobalvars.h ,with the *declaration* in the main.cpp and in the window.h. and *define* it in the main.cpp.

At compile time the *main* has the declaration and the definition of the function, the *window* has only the declaration, but at link time the implementation of the function is found in the *main*, so the *window* can call it from there!

Have fun!